# How to delete a MIME type in Linux/Gnome?

Tags: mime-types

Linux associates the `*.key` files to the `application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey` mime type, which corresponds to an Apple MacOS application.

I don't open Apple files in my Linux PC.

I would like to delete/erase/unbind such MIME type association

How can I delete the MIME types: `application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey` and `application/vnd.apple.keynote` ?

When I open the file `/usr/share/mime/application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey.xml`, I see this comment :

```
<!--Created automatically by update-mime-database. DO NOT EDIT!-->
```